# Typescript Error: Type 'Env' does not satisfy constraint 'ValidResult'

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables

I'm using a library called [EnvObj](https://github.com/matthewmueller/envobj) to help me set up my environment variables in a Node project written in Typescript. My env.ts file looks like this:

```
import env = require('envobj')

export interface Env {
  "PORT": number,
  "PG_CONNECTION" : string,
  "REDIS_CONNECTION": string,
  "SERVER_HOST": string,
  "SERVER_SECURE": boolean,
  "COOKIE_KEY": string,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID": string,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET": string,
  "GOOGLE_API_DOMAIN": string,
  "CLEARBIT_API_KEY": string
}

export default env <Env>({
  "PORT": 3000,
  "PG_CONNECTION": String,
  "REDIS_CONNECTION": String,
  "SERVER_HOST": 'localhost:3000',
  "SERVER_SECURE": false,
  "COOKIE_KEY": String,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID": String,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET": String,
  "GOOGLE_API_DOMAIN": '',
  "CLEARBIT_API_KEY": String
})
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
src/support/env.ts:16:20 - error TS2344: Type 'Env' does not satisfy the constraint 'ValidResult'. Index signature is missing in type 'Env'.
```

If I dig into envobj the ValidResult interface looks like this:

```
interface ValidResult {
    [key: string]: string | number | boolean
}
```

Which seems to be compatible with the Env interface as written.

Adding an index signature to the Env object gives me this error:

```
src/support/env.ts:17:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ "PORT": number; "PG_CONNECTION": StringConstructor; "REDIS_CONNECTION": StringConstructor; "SER...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config<Env>'.
  Property '"PORT"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

 17 export default env <Env>({
                             ~
 18   "PORT": 3000,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 27   "CLEARBIT_API_KEY": String
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 28 })
    ~
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you realy mean to have `String` as the values in your env object? What is its value? It would need to be `string | number | boolean`.

Comment: So e.g. replace Clearbit_API_KEY with an actual API key rather than a placeholder?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, but I'm not familiar with the library or how it's supposed to be used, so this is speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Weird as it might sound, if you specify `Env` as a `type` instead of `interface`, the error will just go away.

```js
import env = require('envobj')

export type Env = {
  "PORT": number,
  "PG_CONNECTION" : string,
  "REDIS_CONNECTION": string,
  "SERVER_HOST": string,
  "SERVER_SECURE": boolean,
  "COOKIE_KEY": string,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID": string,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET": string,
  "GOOGLE_API_DOMAIN": string,
  "CLEARBIT_API_KEY": string
}

// No more error!
export default env <Env>({
  "PORT": 3000,
  "PG_CONNECTION": String,
  "REDIS_CONNECTION": String,
  "SERVER_HOST": 'localhost:3000',
  "SERVER_SECURE": false,
  "COOKIE_KEY": String,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID": String,
  "GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET": String,
  "GOOGLE_API_DOMAIN": '',
  "CLEARBIT_API_KEY": String
})
```

Comment: @dshipper I didn't understand either. So I posted a question right after this answer. According to jcalz, it's a known issue, probably related to a defect in indexability of interface. Check [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815053/3617380) for detail.