# Typescript: Why type alias satisfies a constraint but same interface doesn't?

Tags: typescript

I ran into this weird case. I declare a conditional type. For the same `extends` constraint, a type alias satisfies it, while a structurally identical interface doesn't.

I'm so lost, why the difference? Check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Constraint%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ATypeAlias%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20str%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20num%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20bool%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SameInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20str%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20num%3A%20number%0D%0A%20%20bool%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20expectToBeTrue%20%3D%20ATypeAlias%20extends%20Constraint%20%3F%20true%20%3A%20false%0D%0Atype%20butWhyAmIFalse%20%3D%20SameInterface%20extends%20Constraint%20%3F%20true%20%3A%20false).

```js
interface Constraint {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean
}

type ATypeAlias = {
  str: string
  num: number
  bool: boolean
}

interface SameInterface {
  str: string
  num: number
  bool: boolean
}

type expectToBeTrue = ATypeAlias extends Constraint ? true : false

// Wat???
type butWhyAmIFalse = SameInterface extends Constraint ? true : false
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've run into a known issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) whereby [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) are inferred for type aliases but not for interfaces.  This is one of those few places where type aliases and interfaces differ in type analysis.  According to [@RyanCavanaugh](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh) (Development lead for the TypeScript team at Microsoft), this is [by design:](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024)

> Just to fill people in, this behavior is currently by design. Because interfaces can be augmented by additional declarations but type aliases can't, it's "safer" (heavy quotes on that one) to infer an implicit index signature for type aliases than for interfaces.

For a while this issue was kept open as a suggestion to change the behavior, but it was ultimately [declined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#event-7848028630) with the [comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-1320620897):

> Changing the behavior at this point would honestly be an incredibly disruptive breaking change without much concrete upside. For clarity, I'm going to close and lock this - interfaces should declare an explicit index signature if they intend to be indexed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and links. I don't see why it's "safer" though :-/