# Typescript as type casting vs as interface casting / assignment

Tags: typescript, casting

Can someone explain, please, why line with cast to interface show error in this code:

```js
 type Json =
  | null
  | undefined
  | boolean
  | string
  | number
  | Json[]
  | { [k: string]: Json }

interface IJson {
  field: string;
}

type TJson = {
  field: string;
}

// this line causes error
// Type 'IJson' is not assignable to type 'Json'.
//   Type 'IJson' is not assignable to type '{ [k: string]: Json; }'.
//     Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'IJson'.(2322)
const i: Json = {} as IJson

// but this line is OK
const t: Json = {} as TJson
```

link to Typescript playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/AQFwngDgpsBSDOB7AdsAvAKGMAPsZArgDZFa7AHIAmUAZgJbJRVl4BGiiRUAhsq8HggATowDmAwgFs2UYQIQoA2gF0BAb2BKA1gC5BI8Sv2LUAXwwZGIObR4BjGAElTwdWQZQiVfUNHIxAG4MCwxwaGAAFVc0Nw96Lx8DfyCQy3sUIWB6EyRUWPUzYB54YBc8jAzkLJBclHQ3IpKo0wwgA

UPD:
There is no error in casting, sorry for misleading title, but with assignment. `IJson` is not assignable to Json, BUT `TJson` IS assignable to `Json`. Why?

Comment: Ah, you've run into [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), which is intentional behavior.  See the [linked q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55814516/2887218) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, didn't find that one!

Answer (score 0):

`A as B` works if `A` can be assigned to `B` OR `B` can be assigned to `A`.You may need to assign the type to `unknwown` first:

```
 const foo: Json = { field: "test" } as unknown as Record<string, IJson>
```

1. `data as unknown` works because anything can be assigned to unknown
   and therefore `data` can be assigned to `unknown`
2. `unknown as Item` works because again anything can be assigned to
   unknown and therefore Item can be assigned to `unknown`.

`data as unknown as Item` works because 1 && 2 are allowed.

Comment: But why there is no error with casting to the same-looking `type`? As far as I understand, types and interfaces interchangeable almost in any case, except some cases, like unions.

Comment: If you look closely you will see that there is no error in casting, but with assingment. `IJson` is not assignable to `Json`, BUT `TJson` IS assignable to `Json`. Why?