# In typescript, why use type can define but use interface will report an error

Tags: typescript, interface, declaration, mapped-types

declares an interface of type A

```js
interface A {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  like: string[];
}
```

I want to set all the values ​​in the A interface as readonly attributes

```js
interface B {
 [p in keyof A]: A[p]
}
```

the will throw an exception, but using type will not

```js
type B = {
  readonly [p in keyof A]: A[p]
}
```

How can this be achieved through the interface, or why can’t the interface be defined? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: _"will throw an exception"_ - I get a compile-time error with TS 5.1.6, and **not** a runtime exception. Please clarify exactly what error message you're getting.

Comment: My side is also throwing an exception at compile time, but I want to know why I can't use interface to define, my mistake is that I can't use: "A" only represents the type, but it is used as a value here

Comment: The curly braces in mapped types (with `in` in them) are part of the syntax and do not allow arbitrary properties added to them.  It doesn't work in an interface for the same reason that interfaces cannot directly be unions or intersections... it's a separate type operator. You can define `B` as an interface [like this if you want](https://tsplay.dev/wXlxkw).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz What would be the point of that empty interface?

Comment: @Bergi (It's not *really* an empty interface, it has three members.)  The "point" is hard to say; there are a few places where interfaces and equivalent types behave differently, such as you can't [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) into interfaces, and [interfaces don't get implicit index signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815053/2887218)... so if you care about those you might want one or the other.